# What is the easiest way to set up a PHP-enabled web server on Windows XP?

Tags: php, windows-xp, web-server

I need a web server with PHP support on Windows XP.

I tried both plain Apache and WAMP, both installing fine but failing spectacularly with cryptic DLL-related errors when started. I tried googling the errors but so far weren't able to get it working.

I don't need anything fancy, I just want to be able to go to http://localhost/index.php and have my PHP code executed and the result printed to my browser window.

Is there some easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

One word: [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html)